# How do i integrate Tiny MCE to `ASPxGridView` when use `EditItemTemplate` in `GridViewDataTextColumn`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce, devexpress, aspxgridview

How do i integrate Tiny MCE to `ASPxGridView` when use `EditItemTemplate` in `GridViewDataTextColumn` ??

i try this

```
  tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode: "exact",
            elements: '<%=editorTxt.ClientID%>',
            theme: "advanced", ....
```

ASPX

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DETAIL" VisibleIndex="3" Visible="false">
   <DataItemTemplate>
     <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" EncodeHtml="False" Text='<%#Eval("DETAIL") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>

</DataItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="editorTxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DETAIL") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

but error raised `CS0103: The name 'editorTxt' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 1):

Using TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor in a GridView Control is explained in detail on link below :

http://crushthesoul.com/using-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-gridview-control.aspx

hOPE THIS HELP..

Comment: Thanks @wajid-ali , but it's still didn't work in ASPxGridView :(

Comment: Does it work if you place the "editorTxt" into, for example, Repeater/ItemTemplate? (i.e. a standard template container).

Comment: @Mikhail no, it doesn't work neither. I guess Devexpress ItemTemplate prevent java script execution.